# Functions $g(x)/h(x),h(x)/f(x)$ are constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f$, $g$, $h$ are functions from the set of positive real numbers into itself satisfying $f(x)g(y)=h(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ for all $x$, $y\in (0,\infty)$. 
Show that the functions  $g(x)/h(x)$, $h(x)/f(x)$ are constant.

I've already shown $f(x)/g(x)$ constant by showing the derivative of $f(x)/g(x)$ to be zero. But I'm not getting how to proceed for $g(x)/h(x)$ and $h(x)/f(x)$. I've already tried by applying the definition of derivative for the latter, but of no use.

Are there some special properties for the functions with open intervals as domain and codomain?
Please help me solve this. Any suggestions are heartily welcome.
Thank you(:>)

Comment: What about rewriting the variables in polar coordinates? $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\theta = \arctan (y/x)$ (since $x,y\in (0,\infty)$). Then you can write $y = r \sin \theta$ and $x = r \cos \theta$.

Comment: How do you know that the functions are differentiable? Is it an extra assumption ? How about continuity?

Comment: @sqtrat You are right, but it seems to me that swapping $x$ and $y$ shows immediately that $f/g$ is constant.

Comment: @Siminore I'm just pointing out that I don't think one should use differentiability if not necessary.

Comment: @sqtrat Yes, of course.

Comment: @sqtrat:yeah,its nothing mention of the differentiability,it means i;ve done it wrong(:>(

Comment: This seems to be (almost) the same question as [Functions $f(x)/g(x), g(x)/h(x),h(x)/f(x)$ are constant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679313/functions-fx-gx-gx-hx-hx-fx-are-constant). (Which was shown in the list of related questions on the right.) The only difference I can see is that the other question does not mention continuity of $f$, $g$, $h$.

Comment: What is somewhat strange is that the first revision of [the older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1679313/1) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1766766/1) contained the same typo in the word [sic] *satsifying*.

Comment: @MartinSleziak:Yeah;this is same,but still I'm not getting  how Dan Robertson is proceeding.

Comment: This also seems to be related to [Maxwell's theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105418/very-elementary-proof-of-maxwells-theorem).

Comment: @MartinSleziak:You may be right,But I'did'nt get what it is saying

Comment: I am curious to know where this problem comes from.

Comment: @PKStyles I have posted my attempt at the duplicate question. (However, I do not know how to avoid using continuity.) I second Siminore's request: It would be nice to know what is the origin of this problem.

Comment: @Siminore:This question was asked in MSc entrance exam of Chennai mathematical Institute in 2011

Comment: Please solve this.I've tried very hard

Comment: @Siminore:http://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/pgmath2011.pdf see question no-5 of part B

Comment: hey!  is there any one who can solve this.