# Is there an analog of Maxwell's theorem on the unit ball?

Tags: probability-theory

[Maxwell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem) says that any product measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is invariant to orthogonal matrices (meaning that the measure of $A$ and the image of $A$ under any orthogonal map $Q$ is the same) is a Normal distribution of the form $N(0, \kappa I_n)$ for $\kappa > 0$.

Is there an analogous statement when instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we make the space the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I believe (but may have made a mistake) -- assuming the measure is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure -- that it [essentially equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105470/503984) to find $f(x) = \prod_i \phi(x_i)$ where $\phi$ solves the equation $\phi'(x) = c x \phi(x)$ and satisfies the boundary conditions induced by $f$ being a probability measure on the unit ball. Here $c$ is a  constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only product measure on the unit $n$-ball $B^n$ which is orthogonally invariant is the Dirac measure at the origin. (Edit: as with the usual Maxwell's theorem we need $n \ge 2$ here because the $n \le 1$ cases are degenerate.)

You can see this by asking what the support of such a measure can be. As a product measure with support contained in $B^n$, its support must be contained in a product of intervals $[a, b]$ (given by intervals containing the supports of its factors) contained in $B^n$. So its support must be contained in the largest $n$-cube inscribable in $B^n$. This cube takes the form $[-s, s]^n$ where $ns^2 = 1$, so $s = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

But by orthogonal invariance the support of the measure must be a union of spheres (edit: centered at the origin). So the support must be contained in the largest ball inscribable in this $n$-cube. This is a ball of radius $s = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$!

Iterating this argument shrinks the radius by a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ each time; we conclude that the measure can only be supported at the origin.

Comment: Welcome back to MSE! When you say „union of spheres“, you mean an arbitrary union of spheres around the origin, right?

Comment: @Maxiliam: thanks! Yes, that's what I had in mind.